# How do I make my app wait until AsyncTask has finished its work before moving on to other tasks (Android)

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am doing a geocoding get request using AsyncTask which needs to finish executing, before proceeding to call another AsyncTask which will use the results from the geocoding request to make another call to another endpoint from the MainActivity.

I thought about forcing it to loop in a while using a "done" flag, set by the first AsyncTask, that may not even work however and it seems very hacky. Does anybody have an idea how to handle this?

Answer (score 1):

`AsyncTask`s have the hook method [`onPostExecute()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onPostExecute(Result)), where you can process its results.

From there, you can simply trigger any methods you want to be executed after the `AsyncTask` is finished.

For example:

```
 protected void onPostExecute(Long yourResult) {
     processYourResult(yourResult);

     // Method startMoreLogic() will be executed after the AsyncTask is finished.
     startMoreLogic();
 }
```

Comment: Good call, I hadn't thought of that. I'll give it a shot.

Answer (score 0):

make your asynctask as a private class and put everything that wait for result at onPoseExecute().

Or add .get() to the method where you call your asynctask.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried both solutions and both suggestions worked!